# Is there a tool for helping the extraction of localizable text from Xaml?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, localization

I am tasked with the localization of a Windows Phone 7 application. The first step is to replace the actual visible text with an ID and put the ID and the text in a resource file.

This is a very tedious work and I was wondering if there are tools for this to automate?

I am thinking along the lines of the gettext package and .po files used in the linux world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a codeplex project that may help you some.  http://xlocalization.codeplex.com/.  To use this method, each control that is to be localized must have the name property assigned.

I tried it with my existing project, and got results that were mixed, but in the long run, I decided to do it by hand.  I don't remember specifically what the problems were that I had, but if you want to try it on a copy of your project, it won't take much time.  If it works for you (and if your controls to be localized all have names), it could save you time.

Also, I don't know how familiar you are with localizing, but I wrote a blog on the subject that takes you from start to finish.  It's at http://www.hopnet.mobi, click Blogs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this will get a lot of traditional answers, but I would also like to put forward something completely original we tried (and succeeded) doing ourselves for more efficient localisation of Silverlight using Attached Properties instead of binding:

[Localisation of Silverlight projects after completion](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?cat=23)

To pre-populate the database we wrote a XML parser to find our markers in all our project's XAML files (XAML is just a subset of XML after all). We could not find any existing tools to do what you suggested, but our requirements were simplified by our new method of localisation (no resource files and no horrid bindings).

*(yes, this is almost the same answer as a previous one of mine today, but it seems to fit again).*

Answer (score 1):

Also for future reference keep an eye out for this tool: http://www.neovelop.com/ This tool will go in private beta soon and looks very promising. Judging from their preview movie this will do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: This looks very promising. I subscribed to the early access program. Thanks.