# Silverlight localization options

Tags: .net, xml, silverlight, localization

I'm trying to add dynamic localization to the existing silverlight app following this guide: [Localization Guide](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/06/21/dynamic-localization-in-silverlight.aspx), unfortunately it doesn't seem to work even though I did the exact things. The guide was inspired from tim heuer's localization article on his blog which is also based from MSDN documentation.

The project uses Silverlight 4 and .NET 3.5. The guide does work on a new application, no problem about that. Since it kinda doesn't work for me, **are there other ways to implement localization? (put all translations in an xml perhaps? load via database? other ways of loading from RESX files?)**

WCF RIA isn't an option I guess since I'm only using .NET 3.5. Do correct me if I'm wrong on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of useful options/answers here: [Is there a tool for helping the extraction of localizable text from Xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953620/is-there-a-tool-for-helping-the-extraction-of-localizable-text-from-xaml/6953950#6953950)

Our own answer there will direct you to this rather novel approach: 
[Localisation of Silverlight projects after completion](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?cat=23)

My personal preference is to pull the required language from a database down at app startup and cache it in ISO storage. For a large app you are still only talking a couple of hundred Kb of data to download, per language, so quite manageable *on the fly*. Central databases are much more convenient for updates (and we allow for dynamic submission of corrections from the client apps).

*PS. WCF RIA services works fine with .Net 3.5 (unless there was some late breaking change).*

Comment: your answer incorporates RIA into the solution but RIA seems to only work on .net 4.0 (i tried downgrading an existing wcf ria to 3.5 but assembly errors popped up). I'll double check it though just to be sure.